# Test whether phones could be connected using Android Emulator

Tags: android

Could anyone tell me is it possible to test an android application that connects two phones using wifi(or any network connection) with the help of two *Emulator* instances.

We would like to make an social networking app that uses location services in android.But since I don't have an android phone I would like to know whether we could test the application using two *Emulator* instances.

Answer (score 0):

Of cause you can connect to devices as many as you have. First you can connect to your phones via USB and run "`adb tcpip`" to set all the device to restart ADBD on network interface. The you can do "`adb connect IpAddressOfEveryDevice`". To direct command to specific device, use `adb -s IP:PORT command`

Comment: :I think you have misunderstood my post.I would like to know whether we could use two _emulator instances_ instead of two phones to test whether the application is working.